# Realm swift sync local database?

Tags: ios, realm, swift2

I'm using `Realm` in my app to store user-created data. Now I want to sync local database so that user can use same data in other iOS devices. I found that [realm](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-mobile-platform/) support data sync on `Realm Object Server`. But couldn't understand how it will work? or what I need to change in my existing code to enable data sync?

Note: I'm using `Swift 2.3` and `Realm 1.0.2`(Yes, it is an old project).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Realm Mobile Platform to sync your database however right now you must setup RMP and the Realm Object Server on your own server (or Mac/Linux computer). You will need to upgrade the version of Realm that you're using to the latest version so you can access the APIs included for the sync component. However, once that upgrade has been completed, no Realm database code will need to be changed to make use of sync or ROS.

Comment: Thanks Willow for your help. One follow up question- Does Realm provide servers in enterprise edition? or we have to configure own servers ?

Comment: Hi @Bharat. Realm doesn't offer Realm-managed servers for any of the editions but please reach out to sales@realm.io if you have any other questions about the enterprise edition.